# Javascript on Oxygen Builder

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html5-video

I have an issue with JS in oxygen Builder for wordpress. I try to integrate a video and I found a JS script to resize it (to make it responsive).

Video source: .webm

```js
// Find all YouTube videos
// Expand that selector for Vimeo and whatever else
var $allVideos = $("video[src^='//site-web.fr']"),

  // The element that is fluid width
    $fluidEl = $("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

  $(this)
    .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

    // and remove the hard coded width/height
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

  // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
      .width(newWidth)
      .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

And I get this error message:
TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$("video[src^='//site-web.fr']"', '$' is undefined) on line #3.

Comment: Why add that `^` to your `$("video[src^='//site-web.fr']"`? What does it achieve?

Comment: I don't know, I guess it's for regex or something like that. It doesn't matter, with or without the "^", I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, in Oxygen builder you have to call with jQuery and not with $. So:

```js
// Find all YouTube videos
// Expand that selector for Vimeo and whatever else
var $allVideos = jQuery("video[src^='//clef-energies.fr']"),

  // The element that is fluid width
    $fluidEl = jQuery("body");

// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {

  jQuery(this)
    .data('aspectRatio', this.height / this.width)

    // and remove the hard coded width/height
    .removeAttr('height')
    .removeAttr('width');

});

// When the window is resized
jQuery(window).resize(function() {

  var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();

  // Resize all videos according to their own aspect ratio
  $allVideos.each(function() {

    var $el = $(this);
    $el
      .width(newWidth)
      .height(newWidth * $el.data('aspectRatio'));

  });

// Kick off one resize to fix all videos on page load
}).resize();
```

Comment: Hi julian I'm having the same problem with this javascript https://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV
But when I replace all the $ it still tells me that there is an error in line 4, that window is not specified. Could you help me with that?